# Make top element fade out and bottom element fade in on mouseover, then make top element fade back in after mouse stops hovering?

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, transition

I'm trying to set something up on tumblr so I can basically make one element change to another one when the mouse hovers over it, e.g.: make a picture change into a box of text when the mouse hovers over it, but when the mouse moves off the text box, it changes back to the picture.

Ideally, I'd like there to be one word on top of a picture, and when I hover over the picture, the one word disappears, and the rest of my text comes in.

[here is an example of what I want to happen](http://www.brendan.tk)

I have been searching for hours, and I haven't been able to find anything like how I'm doing. If you want to see the code, I got it from [here](http://larrystylinsons.co.vu/post/46804462894).

There is a lot of code and I have honestly no idea what I'm doing. I tried pulling the code from the example and cross planting it into my code, but there was too much.

If someone knows what I'm trying to accomplish by the example given, would you mind setting it up in a jfiddle so I can see what I'm trying to do? Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

It can be implemented by jQuery [**hover**](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) and [**animate**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Here is [**my sample code**](http://jsfiddle.net/HaUJx/2/).

html:

```
<img id="bg" src="http://www.stockfreeimages.com/White-and-grey-clouds-thumb10225136.jpg"/>       
<div class="title box">title</div>
<div class="content box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate</div>
```

script:

```
$("#bg").hover(function(){
 $(".title").stop().animate({left:"300px",opacity:0.0},1000,function(){$(this).hide()});
    $(".content").fadeIn();
},function(){
    $(".title").stop().show().animate({left:"100px",opacity:1.0},1000)
    $(".content").fadeOut();
});
```

css:

```
.box{
    position:absolute;
    left:100px;
    color:white;
    z-index:1;
    pointer-events:none;
}
.title{
    top:70px;
}
.content{
    top:100px;
    width:300px;
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with duration controls built in to jQuery function.

Here is a JSFiddle example:    [CLICK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ud6B9/7/)

HTML:

```
<div class="image-holder">
    <div class="slide-in">Bob Marley</div>
    <div class="fade-in">Open your eyes, look within. Are you satisfied with the life you're living?</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-holder {
    position: absolute;
    width: 350px;
    height: 400px;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    background-image: url("http://samuiartsandcrafts.com/images/watermarked/1/thumbnails/1/400/bob-marley-pop-art-e.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.slide-in, .fade-in {
    position: absolute;
    font-family:"Courier", sans-serif;  
}
.slide-in {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 10px;
    top: 0;
    font-size: 22px;
}
.fade-in {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    width: 350px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.image-holder').hover(function () {
    $('.fade-in', this).stop().animate( {
        opacity: 1});
    $('.slide-in', this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 0,
        left: "120px",
    }, 1000);
}, function() {
    $('.fade-in', this).stop().animate( {
        opacity: 0});
    $('.slide-in', this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 1,
        left: "10px",
    }, 1000);
});
```